# Count number of sessions

Tags: php, session, count

I have made a simple webshop script and it works fine! The only thing I'm struggling with now is that I want to make a PHP function which counts how many products the user has in their shopping cart.

I store all the data in sessions. Every product has its own session. Product 1 has cart_1, product 2 had cart_2 etc. If the user has 3 times product 1 in his cart the value of cart_1 will be 3. I want to count all values of sessions which start with 'cart_' I Does anyone know how to manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one session per user, not one session per product. When a user adds a product to the shopping cart, save that information in the user's session:

```
// User would like to order $count items of $product
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$product] = $count;
```

That way, you can `count($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])` to determine how many products the user would like to order and `array_sum($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])` to determine how many items the user would like to order.